# Add Admin role in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I have a database that in this: Admin has *True* **isAdmin** property, but other users have *false* **isAdmin** property.

I want to check if the user who logged in is an **Admin** or **not** by redirecting them to different pages in my app. My code in Controller is:

```
public function store(User $user)
{
    if (auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
        if ($user->isAdmin == 1) {
            return redirect('/ShowUser');
        }
        {
            return redirect('/lo');
        }

    }
    return back()->withErrors(
        [
            'message' => 'Error'
        ]
    );

}
```

But this code doesn't work; it sends the users to `'/lo'` all the time. How can I fix it?

Comment: what about `if ($user->isAdmin) { //Code here...}`?

Comment: For **User-Role-Permission** management in **Laravel** i suggest [this](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust).

Comment: @ako this code check user isAdmin property in Database

Comment: OK. No problem. Please show your `User` **Model** code and what is the exact value of  `isAdmin` in the database ? `1/0` OR `True/False`.

Comment: value of is_admin is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `else` keyword.

Right here:

```
if ($user->isAdmin == 1) {
    return redirect('/ShowUser');
}
{ // <-- right here
    return redirect('/lo');
}
```

add the `else` keyword.

```
if ($user->isAdmin == 1) {
    return redirect('/ShowUser');
}
else { // <-- right here
    return redirect('/lo');
}
```

anyway, your code will still run fine even after the edit above. But I have questions for you:

- Is the `user` assumed to be in the database already?
- What is the default value of `isAdmin` in the database?
- Are you passing the `isAdmin` attribute as an input from a form or something?
- And why is it a `store` request when you're just trying to **log** a user **in**?

It's a bit confusing. I can tell from your code that you're trying to log a user in, but you're doing it in a `store` method (nothing wrong with that, just convention), the `store` method is usually used in **storing** data (how coincidental!)

Comment: yes, as I've said, it will still work even if you didn't add the `else`, furthermore, what are you trying to do? are you trying to log the user in? try to `dd($user)` and then try to `dd(Auth::user())` so we can see the problem.